# XAML Binding path to variable

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I need to bind the text property of a text box to an item stored in a Dictionary and I have to get it by dictonary's key name , but the problem  is that the name is binding in the Tag property and I have no more information since it is built by a static resource into a style
This would be what I want to do:

In the code behind:

```
Dictionary<string,string> filters  = new Dictionary...... ;
```

In XAML

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="StyleName">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox Tag="{Binding}" Text="{Binding Path=filters[Tag]}", Mode= TwoWay}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In this case Tag in "filter[Tag]" is not a dictionary's key but a property Tag of Textbox.

Does somebody know if it is possible to do that? or another way to build. this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use converter. Pass Tag and dictionary there, let it extract value from dictionary based on Tag value.

Comment: You can add 'MyTAG' property to viewmodel and return real TAG